# Performance optimization of searching using for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I need your help in optimizing the below code. I have been experiencing like 2 seconds for each data retrieval and I'm not sure how else I can optimize this code to make it faster.

Below is the code that takes input as number of files (`numaccfiles`), list of files (`accfilelist`), 'outage' is the input for which the data needs to be retrieved and 'desc' is the input to verify if exists.

I need to search through 8 different files to find out if the input 'outage' exists in each file and if so then set "conexist", "converged", "N1results" for each file.

```
def GetN1results(numaccfiles,accfilelist,outage,desc): 
    import os, sys
    import pssarrays, psspy 
    conexist=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    converged=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    con=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    N1results=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    for i in range(numaccfiles):
        conexist[i]=False 
        converged[i]='NA'
        for j in desc[i]:
            if outage[1]==j[1]:
                con[i]=j
                conexist[i]=True
    for k in range(numaccfiles): 
        if conexist[k]==True:
            data=pssarrays.accc_solution(accfilelist[k], colabel=con[k][0])
            N1results[k]=data
            converged[k]=data.cnvflag
    return N1results,conexist,converged
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please give an example of the input files, as well as expected output?

Comment: ACCFilelist is ".acc" file which is the output from Siemens PSS/E Contingency Analysis is not in a readable format for any text reader. My question is that if the index positions as shown in the question remains same, is there a better way to loop through the file for each "outage" and "description" inputs that takes less time to retrieve data?